# Shellcode testing gone wrong

Tags: c, windows, assembly, mingw, shellcode

Hey I'm using a bit of code most of you are familiar with. It basically takes an array of characters and casts it as a function pointer. With this code you can theoretically test any shellcode's functionality with it, and it would be a very valuable program for my work, if it would behave... I'm doing this on Windows XP SP3, and am using MinGW's gcc to compile and gdb to debug the damn thing.

Here's what I've got...

```
unsigned char code[] =
"\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90";
main()
{
  printf("Code length = %i...\n",sizeof(code)-1);
  int (*ret)()=(int(*)())code;
  ret();
}
```

So I decided to use nops as the "shellcode" because it's easy on the eye and brain and would probably work no matter what. Unfortunately it doesn't.

When I compile and run the program I get...

```
An unhandled win32 exception occurred in horsefile.exe[3612].
```

...and when I run it in gdb I get...

```
Program received signal SIGSEV, Segmentation fault.
0x00409000 in code()
```

...where 0x00409000 is the entry point address of the shellcode function ret().

I've turned off DEP, as I thought casting the character array, which I thought was on the stack (probably in .data section in reality), and that there was no executing code on the stack (the casting treating the character array data as code on the stack). So I turned DEP off and it's still misbehaving.

Any thoughts? Remember, I'm using the MinGW compiler/debugger suite for Windows on Windows XP SP3.

EDIT - `unsigned char code[]` instead of `char *code[]` ... still doesn't work...
EDIT - Added the `ret (\xc3)` at the end of the "shellcode", still no joy...

Comment: So what do you think the processor will do once it has executed those `nop`s?

Comment: some RET opcode would be needed after those nops

Comment: downvoted as trivial / uninteresting.  Lack of a `ret` at the end of a function is a common newbie error that is easy to solve when you single-step with a debugger.  You have to know asm to design shellcode, so you should work on it and debug it like any other asm function.

Comment: _It basically takes an array of characters_, no, `char *code[]` is an array of pointers to `char`, change to `char code[] = "...";`

Comment: Also add the `const` to hopefully make the byte array part of an executable segment. This is not guaranteed to work.

Comment: "It basically takes an array of characters and casts it as a function pointer." - Undefined behaviour. Read how modern OS execute code, how programs are structured and what measures are taken to exactly inhibit such things. **Before** you start messing with such things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. DEP (Data Execution Prevention) for my Windows XP SP3 VM was actually on after all.

To shut it off on Windows XP follow [these](https://www.zensoftware.co.uk/kb/Knowledgebase/Disabling-Windows-DEP-Data-Execution-Prevention) steps.

For Windows Vista - Windows 10 download and install the [Enhanced Mitigation Experience Toolkit](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2458544), run it, and specify which security settings you want.

Answer (score 0):

Your *shell code* contains nops, a `0x00` opcode and no further known contents. I can see 2 reasons for this to fail:

- The operating system might not let you run code from the segment into which string literals are stored.
- The sequence of operations does not end with a `RET` opcode, so you end up running some random unknown opcodes...

Try changing `code` to `unsigned char const code[] = "\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\xC3";`

Alternately, you can try and define `code` locally in the `main()` function:

```
int main(void) {
    unsigned char code[] = "\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\xC3";

    printf("Code at %p, length = %i\n", (void*)code, (int)sizeof(code)-1);
    int (*ret)() = (int(*)())code;
    ret();
}
```

Neither approach is guaranteed to work, because the location where the compiler stores the `code` array may not be executable.

Comment: I did in fact add the ret opcode, still no joy. I think your first idea is accurate though. In gdb it segfaults at the entry point to the function... which says something is up with that memory address... Should I use malloc to store the character array? Does malloc reserve memory on the stack?

Comment: @August, _Does malloc reserve memory on the stack?_ No, you mean [alloca](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/alloca.3.html), but I doubt that it solves it.

Comment: @August: `malloc` allocates memory from the heap, not from the stack.  I updated the answer with `code` allocated on the stack.

Comment: Memory used for the stack is unlikely to have execute permission.

Comment: unsigned char const code[] = ""; Works by adding the const. Solved.

Comment: @August: that works because the stack is mapped as non-executable, but data and read-only data are mapped with execute permission.  A `const char[]` will use a constant in read-only memory, but a non-const `char[]` local variable will copy the string to the stack.  If you used a global non-const `char[]`, it would still be executable.  Doing stuff like this requires knowing your target platform, or a lot of confusing trial and error.

Comment: Actually, update, I put the unsigned char code[]= statement within the main function and it works now.

Comment: Also, you can have strings stored in the read-only section by initializing as `char *str = "some string"; ` instead of `char str[] = "some string";`. I don't know if that would accomplish the same thing for your purposes as adding `const`, but it's just something to note.