# How to run machine code as a function in c++

Tags: c++, machine-code

system: Windows 10
compiler: MinGW
error: Segmentation fault

I'm trying to run machine code as a function in c++. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int(*fun_ptr)(void) = ((int(*)())("\xB8\x0C\x00\x00\x00\xC3"));
    std::cout << fun_ptr();
    return 0;
}
```

In online compilers like ideone.com program succesfully print 12 and exits. In my computer I receive "Segmentation fault" error. Can anyone help me?

Comment: mov    eax,0xc
ret

Comment: 64 bit architecture  x64

Comment: if you add a `int fun() { return 12; }` in your code and put its pointer instead of your "shellcode", do you see the same instructions when decompiling it? see https://godbolt.org/z/nM859j for example

Comment: Just an idea: A string constant is stored in a data segment. Trying to run this as code might be prohibited (for security. It's not a code segment.) Otherwise it would be too easy for violent code, wouldn't it? (Though, no idea why you got this running on online compiler...)

Comment: @OznOg That was my first idea. I made it vice versa: looked for output of [`int f() { return 12; }`](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/2GSIvL) in Compiler Explorer. Ignoring the useless `rbp`/`rsp` fiddling, it looks not that bad.

Comment: No, I see "\x55\x48\x89\xE5\xB8\x0C\x00\x00\x00\x5D\xC3" but it also do not work

Comment: So there is no way to run user-entered machine code in c ++?

Comment: -fno-set-stack-executable not works

Comment: have a look to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38878823/shellcode-testing-gone-wrong seems to end up with something simlar to your problem

Comment: ill try turn off data execution protection

Comment: after turning off dep code still do not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A string literal such as `"\xB8\x0C\x00\x00\x00\xC3"` is an object of static storage duration [[lex.string]/15](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.string#15). A compiler will typically place such string literal objects in the `.rdata` section of your binary, i.e., into read-only, non-executable memory. As a consequence, trying to execute the bytes of a string literal will result in an access violation. If you want to execute machine code bytes contained in a global array object, you have to make sure your object is allocated in a section that is executable. For example (targeting Windows with Visual C++):

```
#include <iostream>

#pragma section("runstuff", read, execute)

__declspec(allocate("runstuff"))
const unsigned char code[] = {
    0xB8, 0x0C, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xC3
};

int main()
{
    auto fun_ptr = reinterpret_cast<int(*)()>(&code[0]);
    std::cout << fun_ptr();
    return 0;
}
```

Note that stuff like that is inherently not portable and has implementation-defined behavior at best. If you know at build time what machine code you want to run, consider using an assembler and just linking the resulting object file to your executable. If you want to dynamically generate machine code on Windows, you will have to allocate executable memory. To do so, either create a large-enough array in executable (and also writeable) memory (e.g., analogously to my example above) into which you can place your code, or dynamically allocate executable memory, e.g. using [`VirtualAlloc`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-virtualalloc) or using [`HeapAlloc`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/heapapi/nf-heapapi-heapalloc) from a [Heap with the executable flag set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/heapapi/nf-heapapi-heapcreate). You will also want to be aware of the [`FlushInstructionCache`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-flushinstructioncache) API…

Answer (score 1):

I found a method:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    unsigned char bytes[] = "\xB8\x0C\x00\x00\x00\xC3";

    HANDLE mem_handle = CreateFileMappingA(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, NULL, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, 0, sizeof(bytes), NULL);
    void *mem_map = MapViewOfFile(mem_handle, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS | FILE_MAP_EXECUTE, 0x0, 0x0, sizeof(bytes));

    memcpy(mem_map, bytes, sizeof(bytes));
    int result = ((int (*)(void))mem_map)();

    cout << "argument:\n" << result << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by using an inline assembler:

```
#include <iostream>

int code() {
    __asm (
        ".byte 0xB8, 0x0C, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00"
    );
}

int main() {
    std::cout << code() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```