# How can I create simple C++ code that runs fine with no Data Execution Prevention (DEP) but will crash with DEP on?

Tags: c++, dep

While I understand code that is not marked "executable" will trigger a DEP crash, I am trying to understand what type of common coding practices (in legacy Windows apps) would result in this type of crash.

Comment: On which operating system?

Comment: "Common" coding practices? Hopefully none, as few "common" coding practices would include putting code in the data or stack segments for execution. The only place this is "common" would be in hacks, cracks, viruses or other similar things.

Comment: If you fill an unsigned character array with binary machine code instructions and then try to call it as a function.  Something like what this guy was trying to do: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55674951/how-to-run-machine-code-as-a-function-in-c  or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18476002/execute-binary-machine-code-from-c

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude it's common problem in legacy Windows applications at least, including fairly mainstream applications... i debug/patch this problem all the time, but I never work from source code, so wonder how they were created in the first place

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this:

```
int main()
{
    char* s = (char*)malloc(1);
    s[0] = '\xC3';
    void (*p)() = (void (*)())(s);
    p();
}
```

ATL did this to allocate thunk for `WndProc`. The purpose of such WndProc thunks is to embed context parameter and use a method for `WndProc` instead of a function not taking extra context parameter.

The fix is easy enough, and does not necessarily include removal of dynamic code allocation:

- one way is as @Remy pointed out allocate using `VirtualAlloc` and manage rights using `VirtualProtect` to make sure execution right is there.
- easier way is to create a heap with `HeapCreate` and pass `HEAP_CREATE_ENABLE_EXECUTE`, allocate code on that heap
- finally, there are [ATL thunk helpers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/atlthunk/), stating from Windows 10, they can help avoiding having code generation implemented in the program or library. Though this will only work for thunks like ATL thunks, and not a generic solution.

Comment: This is very easy to fix to support DEP, though. Use `VirtualAlloc()` instead of `malloc()`, and use `VirtualProtect()` to grant the memory execution rights after it is populated with machine instructions.

Comment: I've elaborated possible fixes